# How do I install automake and autoconf on RedHat Enterprise 5?

Tags: redhat, yum, upload

I am attempting to install "uploadprogress" for a PHP application, and have failed on dependencies.

Firstly, on phpize, then php-devel, then on autoconf and automake.

I have tried yum, and various repositories, with no luck.

I think it's to do with the ultra-tight but annoying set up they have on Rackspace Cloud servers.

Does anyone know where I can find a repository that I can tell yum to look at that will contain php-devel, autoconf, automake, etc?

Thanks ever so much.

---

**Release details:**
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)

Linux version 2.6.18-128.7.1.el5xen (mockbuild@hs20-bc2-3.build.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)) #1 SMP Wed Aug 19 04:17:26 EDT 2009

Linux Serv001 2.6.18-128.7.1.el5xen #1 SMP Wed Aug 19 04:17:26 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These should be installable via yum and the base RHEL repositories.  Have you tried querying if they are already installed but not in your path?  Also, have you successfully installed anything via yum?

To check what package you need to install:

```
[user@server]# yum whatprovides autoconf automake
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
autoconf-2.59-12.noarch : A GNU tool for automatically configuring source code.
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-5
Matched from:

automake-1.9.6-2.1.noarch : A GNU tool for automatically creating Makefiles.
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-5
Matched from:
```

Comment: It seems I don't have any base RHEL repos in my /etc/yum.repos.d list. How would I add these?

Comment: Further information: these automake and autoconf are not installed.

Comment: You'll need to grab the `redhat-release` package from the media and force-install it in order to restore the base yum repos.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ignacio. However, I only have access to the server over 'the cloud' via an SSH connection. Are there any other ways?

Comment: I think RHEL uses yum-rhn-plugin define the base repo and to get updates - it doesn't need an entry in repos.d, but you do have to have a valid Redhat subscription.  You should probably talk to Rackspace regarding what the update plan is for their RHEL boxes.  You could always repoint RHEL to a CentOS repository but that's a bit involved and likely not the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

These RHEL repositories can be installed using yum utility. A good feature is to enable another repository from your own DVD installation disc. A complete step-by-step description can be found here. http://saifulaziz.com/2014/02/26/howto-install-redhat-package-with-yum-command-without-rhn/

Once you did it, you can install automake, or autoconf from this "new" repository. In other words, you can bypass the warning message of "This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register."